# list operations using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

I want to use list comprehension & wanted to create output as :

```
output1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20]]

output2:
('value', 1)
('value', 2)
'
'
('value', 20)
```

I can create output1 and output2 using for loop but I dont have idea that how I can use list comprehension for the same.

If any one knows this, kindly let me know.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need list comprehension? Please post your `for` loop.

Comment: output2: what's output2? is that a list?

Comment: @Karoly Horvath output2 is below output1, the tuple pairs

Answer (score 8):

For the First you can do something like

```
>>> [a[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(a),4)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20]]
```

For the Second you can simply read and generate the tuples with `value` as the first item

```
>>> [('value',i) for i in a]
[('value', 1), ('value', 2), ('value', 3), ('value', 4), ('value', 5), ('value', 6), ('value', 7), ('value', 8), ('value', 9), ('value', 10), ('value', 11), ('value', 12), ('value', 13), ('value', 14), ('value', 15), ('value', 16), ('value', 17), ('value', 18), ('value', 19), ('value', 20)]
```

another version using itertools.izip_longest though the above is more redable

```
list(itertools.izip_longest([],a,fillvalue='value'))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
output1 = [a[i:i+4] for i in xrange(0,len(a),4)]
output2 = [('value',i) for i in a]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's [JF Sebastians's grouper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312644/21640), which solves your first problem:

```
 from itertools import izip_longest, repeat
 izip_longest(*[iter(a)]*4, fillvalue=None)
```

For your second: `zip(repeat('value'), a)`

Comment: i dont know but its proper answer. i dont know why some people just downvotes and dont give reasons